# State management in React native - Multiple state in same Store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am very new to react native and working on an application where we handle the employee details and use the redux store for state management. The landing page shows the details of the logged-in user.
Based on the employee's title, the actions they can perform within the app vries.
For eg: For an employee role user can update his profile.
For the Manager role, the user can update his profile and his employee's profiles.

When the manager login, his profile is fetched from DB and Store in redux store model and any change in the profile will be updated store model.
Another screen displays all of his employees and he can select an employee to update the profile.

I am using the same component for updating the profile.

How can I manage the state of an employee's profile.?
When I used the same store model, The data on the landing page also updated (i,e the logged-in user's data changed)

How can I reuse the same store model for holding the changes in the employee's profile.?
I can create a new store model for employees' profiles, but I will have to copy all the actions from the store model used for managers, and in the future change in one store will have to be copied to another (This is an extra effort when we have to manage same code in different files)

How can manage 2 states with the same store model?